# How to trim both key and value from an array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an array of objects like below.

```
 {
    "Id": 11,
    "name ": "xxN "
  }
```

How can I use lodash `trim` method to trim both key and value.

```
 {
    "Id": 11,
    "name": "xxN"
  }
```

Expected:

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: added the expected section

Comment: what is difference here?

Comment: after "name ": "xxN " this is the space that I don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, here's a Lodash solution using [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#transform)

```js
const obj = {
  "Id": 11,
  "name ": "xxN "
}

const transformed = _.transform(obj, (result, value, key) => {
  result[key.trim()] = typeof value === "string" ? value.trim() : value
})

console.log(transformed)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This has the added bonus of producing a new object with the same prototype as your original which may or may not be handy.

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to use Lodash? With vanilla JavaScript:

```
result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => 
    [key.trim(), typeof value == 'string' ? value.trim() : value]))
```

Comment: looks promising. But I am using node 10 for my project and getting 
`TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function`,  this error

Comment: @Nick Node 10 does not support `Object.fromEntries`. You have to upgrade to Node 14.

Comment: Yes @Spectric, Thats why I was looking for lodash. Can't upgrade the project to node 14. few things might break. 

Comment: @Spectric I assume he can't upgrade at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash [trim](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/trim/) method

```js
const arr = [
  {
    Id: 11,
    "name ": "xxN ",
  },
  {
    Id: 12,
    "name ": " yyK ",
  },
];

const result = arr.map((o) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k, typeof v === "string" ? _.trim(v) : v])
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla js would be better if you had the support for it but with lodash

```js
var trimmed = _.fromPairs(
  _.map(input, (value, key) => [
    _.trim(key),
    typeof value === "string" ? _.trim(value) : value
  ])
);
```

Comment: Do you need `_.toPairs`? Doesn't `_.map()` work with objects?

Comment: @Barmar Good call